# Can't run my exe file in alpine docker image

Tags: exe, doxygen, gitlab-ci-runner, alpine-linux, bin

I am trying to create doxygen documentation page in gitlab ci-cd

My .gitlab-ci.yml file looked like this:

```
image: alpine 

pages:
  script:
    - apk update
    - apk add doxygen
    - doxygen Doxyfile

  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
```

It works, but it downloads an old version of doxygen and I need a latest one, with the latest features

So I tried to download binaries in zip and unzip it

```
image: alpine 

pages:
  script:
    - apk update
    - apk add zip
    - wget "https://www.doxygen.nl/files/doxygen-1.9.8.windows.x64.bin.zip" 
    - unzip doxygen-1.9.8.windows.x64.bin.zip
    - ls
    - .\doxygen.exe -v
    - .\doxygen.exe Doxyfile

  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
```

The ls command shows that the file is here, but then next step it cant find it
The output looks like

```
$ ls
Doxyfile
README.md
doxygen-1.9.8.windows.x64.bin.zip
doxygen.exe
doxyindexer.exe
doxysearch.cgi.exe
doxywizard.exe
libclang.dll
pom.xml
public
src
/bin/sh: eval: line 136: .doxygen.exe: not found
$ .\doxygen.exe -v
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 127
```

Comment: Did you try without the `.\ ` or with `./`?

Comment: An exe and those DLL libraries are Windows pieces of software. You cannot run those in a Linux container.